# How to create a topic exchange in Qpid JMS for ActiveMQ like RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, qpid, jmstemplate

I've got a Java application that uses RabbitMQ. This application creates a TOPIC exchange and pushes messages to the TOPIC with its own routing key.  From this way if I want the data from any application I create a queue binding with the exchange TOPIC and the routing key I want to.

I want to do the same thing by using a Java application with Qpid JMS as the client and ActiveMQ as the server. The information says it's possible, but I don't know how. I cannot found a specific example seems to RabbitMQ. I can create queues but I don't know how to create the exchange and the binding.  What steps should I follow to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) instead of ActiveMQ "Classic" as the [address model](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) of Artemis is much more similar to RabbitMQ's than the address model from ActiveMQ "Classic" (which is more JMS-centric).

As far as JMS goes I think what you need is:

1. A topic. This is analogous to the "exchange" from RabbitMQ. Any message sent to a JMS topic is delivered to every subscriber. It's basic publish/subscribe semantics.
2. A topic subscriber with a selector. As noted in #1, every subscriber on a topic will get any message sent to that topic, but a JMS "selector" can be used to filter messages similar to the routing key in RabbitMQ.
3. An agreed-upon key for a message property. In order to create a viable selector for the topic subscriber the producer and the subscriber must agree upon the property key to filter on.

If each subscription is going to have lots of messages and those messages need to be shared among multiple subscribers/consumers (e.g. for load-balancing/distribution) then you will need to use a JMS "shared subscription." However, shared subscriptions are only part of JMS 2 and only ActiveMQ Artemis implements JMS 2. You can't use ActiveMQ "Classic" with JMS shared subscriptions as it only supports JMS 1.1.

Both ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis create server-side resources (e.g. topics, queues, etc.) on-demand by default so all you need to do is write your JMS application.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, just one detail, each subcriber is a client with all the data, but if there are many data, is there some way to distribuid the data for the subscription (Something like a queue with multiple consumers)?

Comment: I tried it, the problem is that I use ActiveMQ from Amazon MQ, it only lets me choose ActiveMQ 5.x

Comment: That's unfortunate. Since you're using Amazon MQ (which is based on ActiveMQ 5.x) you won't be able to use any of the features from JMS 2.